# Inserting into Array and comparing Dates Swift iOS Code

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops

I am attempting to create an array that will store 365 integers, it must be filled completely. I am using Healthkit to figure out the users steps from a year back, hence the array size. Every integer represents 1 day.

I have done this in android already and it worked perfectly, I got 365 integers back with 0's for the days with no steps, however, the problem is with iOS health kit I get nothing from days with no data, which I need. In order to do this I thought I would compare the date variable I get with the date of the current day + 1 and loop through the array to see if it find any matching cases, if not put a 0 into it at the end.

So in order to do this I created an array of 365, at the line var ID = 0 is where I attempt to store the integers correctly into the array.  I am using Swift 4.

```
struct stepy {
  static var step = [365]
}
```

This is where I enumerate through the stepData, first at var ID I attempt to compare the date I get in the enumerate loop with the current date (basically index 0 in the array, which represents the first day, the current day).

However I got a problem, currently I believe I would overwrite the days which already has been inputted into the date at the second step enumeration? Also I can't get the date code to compile properly, I just get the Date has no valid member called "add"

```
stepsQuery.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
  let endDate = NSDate()
  let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -365, to: endDate as Date, wrappingComponents: false)
  if let myResults = results{
    myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate!, to: endDate as Date) { statistics, stop in
      if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity(){
        var date = statistics.startDate
        let steps = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())

        var id = 0                  
        var dateToInsert = date
        var today = Date()
        var todaytwo = Date()

        for index in 0..<stepy.step.count {
          if dateToInsert != today  {
            id = index + 1
            today.(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)
            stepy.step.append(0)                          
          }
          if date == dateToInsert as Date {                                    
            today.add(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)
            stepy.step.append(Int(steps))
            id = index + 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create an array of 365 zeros with `var step = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 365)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 static var step = [365]
```

The above doesn't make sense. It does not create an array of 365 integers, it creates an array with one integer in it that is 365. What you need is

```
 static var step: [Int] = []
```

which creates an empty array you can just append your results to

> currently I believe I would overwrite the days which already has been inputted into the date at the second step enumeration?

because your code appends to the array, which is the same as in Java: `myArrayList.add(element)`, this is not a problem.

> Also I can't get the date code to compile properly, I just get the Date has no valid member called "add"

Correct, it doesn't. Also this line:

```
today.(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)
```

does not make any sense. That should be causing a compiler error to.

Anyway, I don't see what the point of all that is. Your outer loop presumably loops through the statistics, one per day, so just do your calculation and append to the array. It'll be oldest first, but you can then just reverse the array to get newest first.